# jQuery watermark not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery watermark and it's not working.

```
  $(function () {
     var watermark = "Enter Phone Number";
     watermark.fontcolor = $(this).col
     if ($("#txtPhone").val() == "") {

        $("#txtPhone").val(watermark);
     }
     $("#txtPhone").focus(function () {
         if (this.value == watermark) {
             this.value = "";
         }
     }).blur(function () {
         if (this.value == "") {
             this.value = watermark;
         }
     });
 });
```

The page is a contentPlaceHolder.

Anything wrong with this?

Comment: Your code actually appears to work just fine. What is the problem? and what is `$(this).col` supposed to be calling? (You're also missing a semicolon there)

Comment: Are you actually calling this function?

Comment: Please try to post a working example in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your code works fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/AdXB3/) Perhaps the problem is with your markup: are you sure that the `<input>` tag has an **id** value "txtPhone" and not just a **name** ?

That line that tries  to set the font color is not going to work as it stands, however. The value of `this` is probably either undefined or else it's the "window" object.

Comment: Hi, Here is my textbox <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>.  Do I have to call it explicitly?

Comment: In ASP, the actual client-side "id" value will not be just "txtPhone" - you have to use some sort of ASP function or something to ask explicitly for the client-side "id".  I'm not an ASP programmer so I don't know how to do it :-(

Comment: @Pointy, he can use `<%= txtPhone.ClientID %>`, assuming the javascript is located in the aspx page.

Comment: @Brandon thanks, I knew it was something like that but I didn't just want to guess :-)  And yes, @Tony, that will work so long as the JavaScript you posted is *inside* the ASP page.  According to some docs I just read, it's possible with ASP 4.0 to tell it exactly how you want it to form the client "id" values, so that you can just "know" what it'll be.

Comment: [This is the page I was looking at](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx) and various others come up in a google search for "ASP 4.0 client id"

Answer (score 1):

Incase you still have problem with watermark plugin use this one http://www.tectual.com.au/posts/8/jQuery-Watermark-Plugin-Best-jQuery-Placeholder-.html. Here is a [watermark sample page](http://www.tectual.com.au/downloads/jquery/watermark/index.html). It support all kinds of watermarking you need.

Answer (score 0):

is your type number or something else(url, email, may be...)???

if yes, it should be changed to text.

```
<input type="text" />
```

not

```
<input type="number" /> or something else like (url, email)
```